# How do I make single, curved characters?

Tags: fonts, latex

I need very often curved, latin Symbols. For example out of this document:
[image: german longhand]
I need something, that looks like the capital "L" and the capital "A". I need that for mathematical formulas. Already found out, that you can use

`\usepackage{pifont}`

in the preamble and for example

`\Pisymbol{pzc}{76}`

to print the character "76" out of the font "pzc". However I don't find any lists containing the fonts and its three-character-long name. Also possible is inside a math enviroment

`\mathcal L`

but it's not quite what I look for. It's not curved enough.

Comment: There are several calligraphic fonts available for LaTEX. See for instance https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html Most cannot be used directly in math mode, but you can define a macro that selects the proper font and char and put it as a box in a formula.

Comment: How do I use the font in text?

Comment: I think I have it \Fontskrivan did first not work and now works

Comment: It changes the whole text, this is not what I want to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `\mathscr` curvy enough?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathscr{L}
\mathscr{A}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]